# Permission issue with upstart script/uwsgi for subprocess (OSError: no such file or directory)

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, uwsgi, upstart

I have a flask app that I run using Nginx and uwsgi. It uses a library that calls some system function via subprocess.

Now if I run the uwsgi server manually everything works just fine:

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini   # all good
```

Then I have an upstart script that runs the thing:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid ubuntu
setgid ubuntu

env PATH=/home/ubuntu/proj/env/bin
chdir /home/ubuntu/proj
exec uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

which is started via `sudo start proj`. The server runs fine, but the library fails like the following:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/proj/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pdfkit/configuration.py", line 18, in __init__
['which', 'wkhtmltopdf'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm suspecting that it's some permissions issue, but couldn't figure out how to get it working. Any insights greatly appreciated!

The processes look almost the same (with `ps aux | grep uwsgi`):

Manual:

```
ubuntu    9958  0.3  4.5 127372 45804 pts/2    S+   09:40   0:00 uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
ubuntu    9963  0.0  4.0 127372 41176 pts/2    S+   09:40   0:00 uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
...
```

Upstart:

```
ubuntu   10020  4.7  4.5 125792 45748 ?        Ss   09:42   0:00 uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
ubuntu   10027  0.0  3.9 125792 40432 ?        S    09:42   0:00 uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
....
```

Comment: I just tried to `setuid root` and `setgid root` and that doesn't work either, fwiw.

Comment: do you have `which` executable in `home/ubuntu/proj/env/bin`?

Comment: I do not. Why does it need to be in that folder?

Comment: do you see `env PATH` in the upstart config?

Comment: ohhh wait ok yeah...